# 'starts with" not working when checking a 'localhost' url

Tags: applescript

I'm writing a handler that will focus on a Safari tab when the window name starts with a substring. Why is this script not working? I've verified the text and it returns true when I isolate the strings (e.g. "localhost:8080..." starts with "localhost"  -- #> true.

```
log focusTabStartingWithName("localhost")

to focusTabStartingWithName(theNameStarting as text)
    tell application "Safari"
    
        set found to false
        repeat with nextWindow in every window
            set tabList to every tab of nextWindow
            try
                repeat with nextTab in tabList
                    set tabName to (name of nextTab) as text
                log "[" & tabName & "]:" & theNameStarting & ":" & (tabName starts with theNameStarting)
                -- #> localhost:8080/somewebapp:localhost:false  INCORRECT!!!
                    set found to tabName starts with theNameStarting
                    if found then
                        tell nextWindow
                            set current tab to nextTab
                            set visible to true
                        end tell
                    
                    
                         exit repeat
                     end if
                end repeat
            on error
                log "Error encountered getting the next tab in the list"
            end try
        
            if found then exit repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
    
    return found
end focusTabStartingWithName
```

Comment: Most likely the URL starts with an URL scheme like `http` which is not being displayed.

Comment: Yeah, mysterious. Tried with 'h11p://localhost' (used 1 to prevent turning to hyperlink) and it still fails. I used `text 1 thru ((count of theNameStarting) + 1) of tabName` and that worked.

Comment: As written, your script asks for the tab's name, not its address. Your script's log generates: (*[AVPlayer's Folder]:localhost:false*). And if you use 'url' then it results in something like: {"http://10.0.1.21:8080/"}. It doesn't use the string 'localhost'. Someone more knowledgeable than I might know exactly why but I don't believe that it is actually part of the address; rather, it is a proxy for it (in the non-technical sense).

Comment: Yes, the handler asks for a tab name and that is desired. I want to be able to focus on a tab given the name of the page. The reason the localhost is returned is that this specific web page didn't have a name, so I would assume that it is Safari that decided to return its URL as the name. I have a working handler that can focus on a matching URL, but it's not what I need for this particular requirement.

Comment: @user3479815 It may be desired but what if it isn't provided. In all likelihood your page does not have a 'name'. 'localhost' isn't a name, neither is an URL or IP address (unless the page provider explicitly makes it so). Check the page's source and look for its <title>. It probably won't have one. Once you confirm that, have your script check for it and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 1 to:

```
log focusTabStartingWithName("http://10.")
```

Change line 9 to:

```
set tabName to (URL of nextTab) as text
```

At your leisure, you can change some of your variable names to more appropriate ones but the above should work as long as the localhost IP begins with '10.'.